# fitnesse - threading issues on older versions

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

For a java project using Slim we have built up a quite a few suites, each with a couple of hundred tests. As these suites have grown we are seeing some pretty random null exceptions occurring more frequently as the suite size increase. 
This would suggest some threading issues.

```
The query method returned: Exception: queryTable_3_2
```

We are using quite an old fitnesse version (20111026), wondering if anyone has issues with such issues in fitnesse and what solved them.

Not seeing any chanage log in regard to release, anyone know has any thread related fixes gone in since v.20111026?

Comment: I don't if there are any specific changes to threading, though the code base has been improved a lot over the past three years. How are you running your tests? I'm also pretty sure that the execution of a test all happens in the same thread, so it should be internally consistent.

Comment: Suites of tests are invoked via jenkins, multiple suits are executing at the same time